# Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration | Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, namespaces, azure-pipelines

- I have a deployment and related K8s resources implemented in a K8s environment under the namespace "A"
- These resources are deployed via an Azure-DevOps release pipeline
- Now I have a requirement to deploy the same set of resources under the namespace "B"
- When I tried by editing the deployment.yaml code and pipeline parameter it's failing and giving the below error

---

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when retrieving current configuration of:
Resource: "/v1, Resource=configmaps", GroupVersionKind: "/v1, Kind=ConfigMap"
Name: "XXXX-XXXX-XXX", Namespace: "B"
```

---

### **My deployment.yaml file**

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: XXXX
  namespace: B
data:

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: XXXX
  namespace: B
spec:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: XXXX
  namespace: B
spec:
```

---

Azure-DevOps pipeline configs
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### **PROBLEM SOLVED**

There were two things to fix in my implementation

1. [OPTIONAL-not a must to perform]Remove the namespace definition in deployment.yaml

---

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: XXXX
  namespace: B
data:

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: XXXX
  namespace: B
spec:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: XXXX
  namespace: B
spec:
```

---

2. Create a new service connection and load it in the CD pipeline
   [image]
3. Be careful to mention the exact namespace and then the new service connection will be dedicated to the mentioned namespace

[image]

4. Deployment was successful

[image]